# split "unbricking" tag: hard-bricked vs soft-bricked devices

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-cleanup

The answers concerning unbricking are substantially different depending on [whether it is a hard-brick/coma or a soft-brick](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1133590).

[An example of a possible hard-brick or coma](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20696/google-io-galaxy-tab-10-1-refuses-to-power-on-any-hope-of-revival) vs [an example of a soft-brick](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23359/galaxy-tab-p7500-wont-boot).

But we have only a single tag `unbricking` for both.

It would be more convenient to search for answers if the tag was split: `hard-unbricking` vs `soft-unbricking`.

Comment: How do you define hard-brick and soft-brick?

Comment: @Flow something like: soft brick -- it powers on, but the boot process never succeeds; hard-brick or coma -- there are no signs that the device is active, it doesn't power on at all. Seen this explanation at xda-developers, and it is really a very substantial difference inside what people call "brick". Like the quooted text at http://www.xda-developers.com/android/explaining-and-advancing-the-unbrickable-mod/ I've found it: I read it at http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1133590

Answer (score 5):

It would be more convenient to search for answers if the tag were split... and it were always used correctly. But most of our visitors have no idea of the difference. Even the existing tag isn't always used appropriately, and I don't think introducing new, finer granularities is going to help that. For this reason, I don't believe that the split you suggest would actually help.

Comment: Though we could correct those tags of *new users* (as those posts would turn up in the review queue). Trouble is, we might miss those, too. Still, a cleanup never hurts, so for the part where it doesn't match at all, it could be removed entirely.

Comment: I am generally of the opinion that if only an expert knows whether a tag is relevant or not, we're just setting up the expert users for a lot of extra work for little real benefit. That's an especially big problem for a site like ours with a low ratio of experts to novices.

Comment: I'm afraid I agree with Dan, here.